# update a table field value with adjoin row

Tags: mysql

First of all I'm not sure this is possible within the `mysql` limitation. Anyway I will post it.

Let say I have a table with `id` and `date`. But due to some reason some of the dates were missing in the table. So what I basically need is, update those missing dates with adjoin row date value.

```
+-----------+---------------------+
|     id    |       date          |
+-----------+---------------------+
|    1000   | 2016-11-22 11:57:59 |
|    1001   | NULL                |
|    1002   | 2016-11-22 12:17:41 |
|    1003   | 2016-11-22 13:09:24 |
|    1004   | 2016-11-22 22:40:31 |
|    1005   | 2016-11-22 13:59:40 |
|    1006   | NULL                |
|    1007   | NULL                |
|    1008   | 2016-11-22 15:10:29 |
|    1009   | 2016-11-22 22:40:31 |
+-----------+---------------------+
```

According to above example I have few rules to update the missing date values for id `1001`,`1006` & `1007` as bellow.

1. if there is any missing date it should always update with the record just above. eg: `1001` will update with `1000` date value which is `2016-11-22 11:57:59`
2. records update must do with the `id acs` order, So that we will not face any trouble for not having the value in the above row. Because even though it is missing initially , but will update with before comes to that row eg:`1007` : `1006` is missing initially, but it will update with `1005` then when it comes to `1007`, `1006` already have a value. finally both `1006` & `1007` have the 1005 date value which is `2016-11-22 13:59:40`

Hope I explain the question clearly, But still I'm not sure this is possible with pure `mysql` query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually this is quite possible with mysql using the update and join. However since you have consecutive nulls you will have to run the query multiple times.

```
UPDATE empties e1, empties e2 set e1.`date` = e2.`date` 
WHERE e1.`date` IS NULL and e1.id = e2.id+1;
```

Note that in this query the value assigned to id=1007 is the value from the row where id=1006 which happens to be NULL. So you will need a second iteration to fix those nulls.

ps: change empties to whatever your table name is.